# "non-numeric argument to binary operator" Execute R Script, Microsoft Azure

Tags: r, azure, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a simple graph using `ggplot` within Microsoft Azure machine learning studio. I'm getting a "non-numeric argument to binary operator" error when I run the script, my code is below:

```
dataset1 <- maml.mapInputPort(1) #Imports "dataset1" from Microsoft Azure

library(ggplot2) #Load ggplot2 package

ggplot(data = dataset1, aes(x = dataset1$DateInt, y = dataset1$Amount) + geom_point())
```

The error doesn't make sense, both `DateInt` and `Amount` are numeric. Is Azure possibly causing the error?

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that you're using the wrong syntax for `ggplot2`.

```
ggplot(data = dataset1, aes(x = DateInt, y = Amount)) +
    geom_point()
```

Comment: I wish I could share all the variations of code I've tried. I've tweaked the code so many times, I've resolved other errors but keep running into new ones. When I run the code above, I get the error "object 'DateInt' not found". I had $dataset1 in front of my x and y variables to get around that error. Does anyone here have recent experience with Azure? I've run code like the one above in R studio and it has worked just fine.